# Creating a JSON object that sums another array into a number

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I'll explain my rather confusing title:
I have created a JSON object that represents a merchants price tag for a specific dish. what I am trying to do is imitate a price of ingredients, and total price from 3 different merchants.
this is completely hard coded so there is no back end at the moment. as you can see I'm really not sure about the syn-text but you get the logic of what I was trying to do.

JS

```
var main = function () {

    var recipeType = {
        0: {"name": "cocktail", "ingredients": ["Booz","Roofis","Green Stuff"]},
        1: {"name": "appetizer", "ingredients": ["Some leaves","Some veggies", "I dunno toast","Cheese or whatever"]},
        2: {"name": "main course", "ingredients": ["A dead animal","its blood", "some potatoes","love","asparagus"]} ,
        3: {"name": "dessert", "ingredients": ["Dough","Some Sprinkly shit", "sugar","more sugar","cream shaboogy pop"]} ,
    }

    var Merchantprices = {

        ampm:{"ingredientPrice":recipeType[0].ingredients == 20,"sumPrice":recipeType[] == ingredientPrice * recipeType[].ingredients.length },
        haCarmel:{},
        tivTaam:{},

    }

    function getRecipeItems() {
        return recipeItems = [
            {
                "id": "recipe0",
                "title": "Grasshopper Cocktail",
                "img": "../images/grasshopper-cocktail.jpg",
                "ingredients": recipeType[0].ingredients,
                "instructions":"shaken not stirred",
                "price": {"ampmPrice":Merchantprices[0].sumPrice,"haCarmelPrice":Merchantprices[1].sumPrice,"tivTaamPrice":Merchantprices[2].sumPrice},
                "type" : recipeType[0].name,
            },
```

Comment: Is this spam? If not, please take out the sarcastic stuff, post code that doesn't throw errors, get some sleep and explain what you want to do a lot better. Thx in advance.